# How to not automatically send a Docusign Envelope and get the URL Instead using the C# SDK

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Currently we are using this method to automatically send the Docusign email to the client.

```
envDef.Status = "sent";

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);
```

However, we would like to not automatically send the email and instead get the URL to the document that docusign created.

How do you do this using the [C# SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/)?

Comment: What do you want to do with the URL?

Comment: We would like to add the link to an email utilizing mailto:.

Comment: You will need to use Docusign Embedded signing. See the code I have posted in the answer. Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **For [Docusign Embedded Signing](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSigning), see the API Recipe [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs#L463)**

> Embedded **Signing** - or the Recipient View workflow - allows users to sign directly through your app or website. When you embed your recipients you are telling the DocuSign platform your app will generate signing URLs, authenticate your recipients, present the signing request, and re-direct once the transaction is complete.

```
// set envelope status to "sent" to immediately send the signature request
envDef.Status = "sent";

// |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

//  Create Embedded Signing View (URL)

RecipientViewRequest viewOptions = new RecipientViewRequest()
{
    ReturnUrl = "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter",
    ClientUserId = "1234",  // must match clientUserId set in step #2!
    AuthenticationMethod = "email",
    UserName = envDef.Recipients.Signers[0].Name,
    Email = envDef.Recipients.Signers[0].Email
};

// create the recipient view (aka signing URL)
ViewUrl recipientView = envelopesApi.CreateRecipientView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, viewOptions);
```

---

- **For [Docusign Embedded Sending](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSending), see the Api recipe [here](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/test/Recipes/CoreRecipes.cs#L370)**

> The Embedded **Sending** view of an envelope allows users to edit the tabs, documents, recipients, and other settings of draft envelopes before sending them out for approval. Similar to Embedded Signing, your app or website can generate a sending URL and integrate directly into your workflow using a Redirect, Webview, or an iFrame.

```
// must set status to "created" since we cannot open Sender View on an Envelope that has already been sent, only on draft envelopes
envDef.Status = "created";

// |EnvelopesApi| contains methods related to creating and sending Envelopes (aka signature requests)
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary =     envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

//Create Embedded Sending View (URL)
var options = new ReturnUrlRequest();
options.ReturnUrl = "https://www.docusign.com/devcenter";

// generate the embedded sending URL
ViewUrl senderView = envelopesApi.CreateSenderView(accountId, envelopeSummary.EnvelopeId, options);
```